# How can I setup a default mapping in Elastic Search when it creates a new Patterned Index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been able to fix my conflicting fields problem as found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47345816/kibana-reports-a-field-is-conflicting-how-can-i-resolve-it).

But it won't fix my problem going forward when more log entries come in that will cause a field to be conflicting (as in `Long` instead of `Float` in my case), especially when it rolls over to create a new Index of a specific pattern (i.e. the next day), for example: log-20170101 on the 1st of January 2017, but on the next day it will become 20170102 which won't have the applied mapping that I applied on the previous indexes.

How can I setup Elastic Search to apply a mapping on newly created Indexes that start with "log"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this concept called [Index Templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html).

By taking my mappings that I defined in the Re-Index process (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47345817/802755)), I was able to setup a Template for the Indexes that forms part of the Index Pattern "log-*".

The added benefit was that, no matter how many times I told Kibana to refresh my Index Patterns it never added new keywords or changed any of the defined types, so I can finally rest in knowing that my given field that was constantly "conflicting" will now be interpreted as `Float` as long as the value is numeric.